# Insert с Update PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Есть сторонняя БД из которой извлекаются строки в виде списка

```
['01.01.2020,' 'Моя запись', 200, 300]
```

и такой записи каждый день добавляется в разном количестве.
Я через Python выполняю запрос к PostgreSQL

```
INSERT INTO (Дата, имя, сумма_1, сумма_2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Где вместо `?` я подставляю список в цикле.
Но записи в БД PostgreSQL дублируются, как избежать дубли?

```
-- Table: public.bdr

-- DROP TABLE public.bdr;

CREATE TABLE public.bdr
(
    "Период" date,
    "ОмсКоммерция" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "СуммаНачальныйОстатокДт" double precision,
    "СуммаНачальныйОстатокКт" double precision,
    "СуммаОборотДт" double precision,
    "СуммаОборотКт" double precision,
    "СуммаКонечныйРазвОстатокДт" double precision,
    "СуммаКонечныйРазвОстатокКт" double precision
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.bdr
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Comment: *записи в БД PostgreSQL дублируются* По какому признаку? *как избежать дубли?* Создать уникальный индекс по требуемому условию и использовать соотв. ON CONFLICT.

Comment: И примерно с каким условием уникальный индекс создавать?

Comment: *с каким условием уникальный индекс создавать?* Да кто ж знает, что **ВЫ** называете словом "дубли"...

Comment: Выполнив INSERT INTO было добавлено 400 строк в PostgreSQL импортированные из другого БД но после, в другом БД добавилась одна строка и их стало 401.
Я повторил INSERT INTO и теперь строк всего в БД стало 801, вместо 401)

Comment: Покажите DDL таблицы.

Comment: Добавил DDL настоящей таблицы в вопрос. Если я правильно тебя понял.

Comment: В структуре отсутствуют уникальные индексы. То есть согласно структуре понятие дубликата - просто не существует. И всё наблюдаемое совершенно правильно и легитимно.

Comment: У второго столба может быть только 2 значения, это ОМС и Коммерция но у каждого из них могут быть одинаковые периоды. Тем самым не могу сделать уникальным Период, так реально сделать если 2 разных таблицы сделать но мне в одной таблице нужно..

Comment: Ничто не мешает создать уникальный композитный индекс: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ("Период", "ОмсКоммерция")`. Тогда уникальной будет лишь их комбинация, а каждое отдельное поле - нет. *У второго столба может быть только 2 значения, это ОМС и Коммерция* А на... зачем тогда тип данных - TEXT? VARCHAR(9) для таких данных - достаточно.

Comment: А есть возможность дать ссылку на какой-нибудь русскоязычный источник и добавить этот код в ответ: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ("Период", "ОмсКоммерция") , это и есть ответ на мой вопрос в целом

Comment: *какой-нибудь русскоязычный источник* Наверное, есть... но я их не пользую, так что не в курсе, где искать. *добавить этот код в ответ* - нет смысла, не тянет оно на полезный кому-то ещё ответ. Просто я не представляю, что человек, столкнувшийся с такой же проблемой, и имеющий такой же объём  опыта и знаний, сумеет сформулировать строку поиска так, чтобы найти этот вопрос и ответ на него.

Comment: Допустим ```INSERT INTO (Период, ОмсКоммерция, СуммаНачальныйОстатокДт) VALUES (?, ?, ?)```  это SQL запрос который я использую, таблица у меня уже создана, так CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ("Период", "ОмсКоммерция") я должен использовать при создании таблицы?

Comment: ALTER TABLE public.bdr DROP CONSTRAINT index_name;

ALTER TABLE public.bdr
    ADD CONSTRAINT p_index UNIQUE ("Период", "ОмсКоммерция")
    DEFERRABLE;